# PHPMailer timeout when trying to send from unoeuro smtp

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

The title says it all. I have a site with is hosted on unoeuro. I'm trying to send an email with PHPMailer but i fails to connect because of timeout each time. I found [this article](https://en.unoeuro.com/support/faq/49/329/) in unoeuro's support area, saying wich port etc to use, so that should be correct.

My script look like this:

```
if(empty($errors)) {
    $m = new PHPMailer;

    $m->isSMTP();
    $m->SMTPAuth = false;
    $m->SMTPDebug = 1;

    $m->Host = 'smtp.unoeuro.com';
    $m->Username = 'no-reply@weboholics.dk';
    $m->Password = 'nothing to see here';
    $m->Port = 25;

    $m->isHTML();

    $m->Subject = 'Message from form!';
    $m->Body = 'From: ' . $fields['name'] . ' (' . $fields['email'] . ')<p>' . $fields['message'] . '</p><p>(' . $fields['phone'] . ')</p>';

    $m->FromName = 'No Reply Weboholics';
    $m->AddAddress('legarth@weboholics.dk', 'Kasper og Kristoffer');

    if($m->send()){
        echo "The mail was send!";
    } else {
        $errors[] = $m->ErrorInfo;
    }
}
```

The Debug only giv me this:

> 2015-09-13 12:15:06   SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Operation
>   timed out (60) 2015-09-13 12:15:06    SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

And the `$m->ErrorInfo` only says:

> SMTP connect() failed.
>   https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Do anyone know how to fix this? Or have made PHPmailer work with unoeuro hosting before?

Comment: No idea of the required settings but it feels wrong to disable`SMTPAuth ` yet provide username and password. It's also a good idea that provide a sender e-mail address or your message will end up sorted as spam if it ever gets sent.

Comment: You say "It only says" when it's including (twice!) a link to some pretty thorough documentation about how to diagnose problems with PHPMailer. These link things are amazing you know, you can click on them and they take you places!